# Polynomials Problem in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, integers

this is my very first question here and I have many others..
So I have this problem that I have no clue about, I hope to get a solution for it and I hope you guys tell me what is it that I need to learn in order to be able to solve such problems

The problem:

**The polynomial f(x) ∈ Z[x] has the root (a), it's known that f(1) − f(15) = 42 and f(3) + f(4) = 181
find  the remainder of the division of (a) by 3.**

Comment: Show and then use that if $x=y\mod b$, then $f(x)=f(y)\mod b$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** Let $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$. Also let $b,x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $x=y\mod b$. Then $f(x)=f(y)\mod b$.

*Proof:* I leave this to you.

Now to the actual question. If $a\in\mathbb Z$ is a root of $f$, that means $f(a)=0$, which also means that $f(a)=0\mod3$. That is, if $f(x)\neq0\mod 3$, then $x\neq a\mod 3$. Since the only possible remainders are $0,1,2$, it is enough to discard two of these possibilities.

Let's look at the other information we have:

$$f(1)-f(15)=42,\\
f(3)+f(4)=181.$$

With the lemma, it follows that
$$f(1)-f(0)=0\mod3,\\
f(0)+f(1)=1\mod3.$$

This is a system of linear equations $\mod3$, which we can solve for $f(1)$ and $f(0)$. We get

$$f(0)=2\mod3,\\
f(1)=2\mod3.$$

So neither $f(0)$, nor $f(1)$ is $0\mod3$, so $a$ is neither $0$, nor $1\mod3$. Which only leaves us with $a=2\mod3$.

Comment: Thank you for answering!